# CVS How to remove a part of a commit

Tags: eclipse, commit, cvs

I just made a commit and by mistake (#%&* mousepad right click) I included a couple of generated folders in the commit, **is there a way to undo a commit step partially?**

I am not after ignoring some folders, the folders have already been added to .cvsignore, I'm after a solution that will allow me to undo the commit of two folders (images and test-data) but keep the rest of the commit.

Adding it to .cvsignore could have been an option if not for the reason that, as I already mentioned, the folders are already added, selecting files individually or adding wildcards is going to be also something really painful, since there are folders within folders...

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you can acces to the CVS repository you have only to delete the files you want to delete in the CVS tree repository (not on the working copy). This might work, I tested it and it works: when I checked out without any ignore and cvs only downloaded the files that I didn't removed on the repository.

If you don't have acces to the repository:

I'm not sure by 100% but the only way I found to solve this issue is to revert this commit, how to revert it?

```
cvs update -j <current rev> -j <old rev> <filename>
```

Then you only have to do a good commit instead of missclicking and all is done.

Sorry about my english level, I'm not native.